# merging large binary files in c++ optimizing

Tags: c++, optimization, file-io, merge

Background:
I have written a modified adler32 checksum routine which generates 64 bit checksums.
I want to check for collisions in the area of upper and lower case alpha, digits, and _.
I have written a generator program that steps through all the combinations of strings in this range up to a given maximum length.
It has an output of sorted binary files up to 4G in size with the results of the checksums.  The 4G limit is due to memory size, although larger files mean fewer files which speeds up the merge and check significantly.
The total data size for up to 6 byte strings is 64 * 64 * 64 * 64 * 64 * 63 = 67,645,734,912 integers or 541GB at 8 bytes per integer.
This is my limit as the next iteraton would result in files adding up to 64 * 541GB or over 34 TB.

The problem:
I have 122 binary files of uint64_t, most of which ar 4GB in size.  Each individual file is sorted.  I need to check if there are any duplicate values across these files.

The following code seems to work, but is estimated to take about 35 days for the checksums of up to 6 byte strings being considered.  Can anyone think of any optimizations or alternate approaches which may be quicker?
Note that I cannot have more than two files fully in memory at once.

Mike

```
struct DataItem
{
    uint64_t data;
    ifstream ifs;
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf;

    explicit DataItem(const string &filename)
        : ifs(filename, ifstream::in | ifstream::binary)
    {
        constexpr size_t bufSize = 1'048'576;
        buf = make_unique<char[]>(bufSize);
        ifs.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf.get(), bufSize);
        readNext();
    }

    void readNext()
    {
        if (ifs.is_open() && !ifs.eof())
            ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data), sizeof(uint64_t));
    }

    bool operator<(DataItem const &other)
    {
        return data < other.data;
    }

    bool operator>(DataItem const &other)
    {
        return data > other.data;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    path givenPath;
    vector<DataItem> data;

    if (argc > 1)
        givenPath = path(argv[1]);
    else
        givenPath = path("*.dat");

    auto directory = givenPath;
    directory.remove_filename();
    if (directory.empty())
        directory = path("./");

    auto extension = givenPath.extension();

    for (auto &p : directory_iterator(directory))
        if (p.path().extension() == extension && is_regular_file(p))
            data.emplace_back(p.path().string());

    sort(data.begin(), data.end());

    uint64_t current = data.front().data;
    data.front().readNext();

    int progress = 0, loop = 0;
    while (!data.empty())
    {
        // bubble the new value to resort the data vector
        auto now = data.begin();
        auto next = now + 1;
        while ((next != data.end()) && (*now > *next))
        {
            swap(*now, *next);
            ++now;
            ++next;
        }

        if (current == data.front().data)
            cout << current << '\t' << (current >> 32) << endl;

        current = data.front().data;

        if (data.front().ifs.eof())
            data.erase(data.begin());
        else
            data.front().readNext();

        ++progress;
        if (progress >= 1'000'000)
        {
            {
                progress = 0;
                cerr << '.';
                ++loop;
                if (loop >= 10)
                {
                    loop = 0;
                    cerr << '|';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered memory mapped files?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I know nothing about memory mapped files, but they do look promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your log is in files you should not keep them sorted during the execution. Simply write hashes as they occur to the log. Writing the log with the hashes lends itself to parallelization. Make sure that you collect large blocks (e.g. 16 MB) before starting a write.

After finishing hashing do the sorting. Avoid bubble sort, it needs O(n**2) time. Merge sort is great for file based sorting. It can be easily parallelized. Without parallelization it needs O(n log(n)) time.

Comment: Thank you for your response.    It seems that I didn't explain myself very well.  
  The program providing to sorted logs is run prior to this.  This program merges the log files and looks for matches without writing the merged files.  Your response helped me realize that not writing the merged files was a mistake.  My "server", an old i5, is now running all cores reducing the 123 log files to 16.  Thanks again for nudging me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed testing the quality of a hash function (which checksum is a variant of) quickly becomes intractable.

Collision resistance is therefore usually tested statistically instead of algorithmically. Some examples include [spectral testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test) to see how well the output is distributed and [chi-squared testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) to see how unpredictably the output changes given some change in the input. 
Also have a look at [NIST SP 800-22](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-22-rev1a/SP800-22rev1a.pdf), which defines some checks for cryptographic hash functions.
Of course dictionary testing is also useful but only to a certain depth.

Note also that testing against short sequences usually doesn't provide sufficient proof of quality, as the behavior of the hash function on longer sequences can be substantially different.
You should at least also check that longer but largely similar datasets do not collide and check for edge cases, like when some internal value turns to 0 or some other critical value (this depends on the specifics of the function being tested).

Having said that, you don't need to read the entire file in memory; since your files are sorted, just open all the files at once and maintain a sliding window per file, moving the "pointer" forward while reading and comparing the entries (the amount of movement will differ per file). Some buffering though will be helpful.